# Is $((A \wedge B) \rightarrow (C \wedge D))$ the same as $(A \wedge B \rightarrow C \wedge D)$?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I'm currently learning propositional logic and was wondering if I could rewrite the first statement as second (just less paranthesis)? 
Could it be interpreted as a totally different statement or it is fine as it is?

Comment: How are you planning to avoid $(A \land B \to  C \land D)$ being read by some as possibly meaning $(A \land (B \to  C) \land D)$?

Comment: You are right, thanks. 
I saw an example alike in the homework I have, hence the confusion.

Comment: Follow up question, can't we use this order of precedence (¬, ∧, ∨, ⟹, ⟺) to avoid such a confusion?

Comment: To expand on @Henry's comment, note that $(A\land B)\to(C\land D)$ is inequivalent to $A\land(B\to C)\land D$ because e.g. if $A,\,B,\,C,\,D$ are all false then $(A\land B)\to(C\land D)$ is true but $A\land(B\to C)\land D$ is false.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [when $A$ is false but $B$, $C$, and $D$ are true.](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((A%E2%88%A7B)%E2%86%92(C%E2%88%A7D))%E2%86%94(A%E2%88%A7(B%E2%86%92C)%E2%88%A7D))